# WebSQL: SQLite Query Returns a Transaction Error

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I am trying to execute an SQL Transaction using WebSQLite. The problem I have is, every time i run the code, i get an SQL error that states: `SQLError {code: 5, message: "could not prepare statement (1 near ")": syntax error)"}`

From mere look, i couldn't figure out what this error means so i tried printing my sql query into the console and it returns this: `INSERT INTO propertiesList (reporterName, propertyType, bedrooms, datetime, furnitureTypes, monthlyRentPrice, notes, propertyLocation, images) 
VALUES ('Israel', 'Flat', 'Studio', '1570494720000', 'Furnished', '150000', '', '', '')`

Also, this is my code structure:

```js
db.transaction(transaction => {
                        transaction.executeSql(
                            `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS propertiesList (
                                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                reporterName TEXT NOT NULL,
                                propertyType TEXT NOT NULL,
                                bedrooms TEXT NOT NULL, 
                                datetime TEXT NOT NULL,
                                monthlyRentPrice TEXT NOT NULL,
                                furnitureTypes TEXT,
                                notes TEXT,
                                propertyLocation TEXT,
                                images TEXT,
                             )`
                        );
                        if (duplicate === true) {
                            msg = 'You have a property that have some similar details with this. Please check and update it instead';
                        } else {
                            const formData = new FormData();
                            imageArray.forEach(image => formData.append('file[]', image));
                            if (imageArray.length > 0) {
                                axios.post(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://laratweet.me/upload_photos`, formData).then(response => {
                                    console.log('from uploading image', response);
                                });
                            } else {
                                let sql = `INSERT INTO propertiesList (reporterName, propertyType, bedrooms, datetime, furnitureTypes, monthlyRentPrice, notes, propertyLocation, images) 
                                VALUES ('${reporterName}', '${propertyType}', '${bedrooms}', '${datetime}', '${furnitureTypes}', '${monthlyRentPrice}', '${notes}', '${propertyLocation}', '')`;

                                console.log(sql);

                                transaction.executeSql(sql);

                                refreshPropertiesList(true);

                                let interval1 = setInterval(() => {
                                    if (listTypes !== undefined) {
                                        let array = [];
                                        for (let i = 0; i < listTypes.length; i++) {
                                            array.push(listTypes[i].propertyType.toLowerCase());
                                        }
                                        listHandler(array);
                                        clearInterval(interval1);
                                    }
                                }, 1000);
                            }
                        }
                    }, onError, onSuccess);
```

My problem is i can't figure what the error is or how to solve it, and now i'm stuck on the project because i can't continue any part of the website unless the 'create' functionality works. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.

Trailing comma after 'images TEXT' in the creation of the table was blocking the creation.

transaction.executeSql(sql) (db wasn't referenced).

```
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
  db.transaction(tx => {
    tx.executeSql(
      `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS propertiesList (
          id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
          reporterName TEXT NOT NULL,
          propertyType TEXT NOT NULL,
          bedrooms TEXT NOT NULL,
          datetime TEXT NOT NULL,
          monthlyRentPrice TEXT NOT NULL,
          furnitureTypes TEXT,
          notes TEXT,
          propertyLocation TEXT,
          images TEXT
       )`
    );
  });

  let sql = `INSERT INTO propertiesList (reporterName, propertyType, bedrooms, datetime, furnitureTypes, monthlyRentPrice, notes, propertyLocation, images) 
        VALUES ('Israel', 'Flat', 'Studio', '1570494720000', 'Furnished', '150000', '', '', '')`;
  db.transaction(tx=>{
      tx.executeSql(sql)
  })
```

> The W3C stopped actively maintaining the Web SQL spec in 2010 and has
>   no plans to maintain it any further. See Web SQL Database.

I advise you to use,

> IndexedDB API is powerful, but may seem too complicated for simple
>   cases. If you'd prefer a simple API, try libraries such as
>   localForage, dexie.js, ZangoDB, PouchDB, idb, idb-keyval and JsStore
>   that make IndexedDB more programmer-friendly.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/web-sql

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API

Comment: It's a school project, and the guideline specifically asked us to use WebSQL so there is nothing i can do about that

Comment: @IsraelObanijesu oh. I will check

Comment: Thanks. You figured it out so fast. I've spent hours checking the wrong place :(  For the ```insert``` query, i don't need to reference the db, i can run multiple queries in one transaction. Anyway, thanks for figuring out the comma error